# Getting coordinates of specific text in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I need to load a PDF in a webpage, and overlay a div wherever a certain text appears. However, I am unable to find the API that will let me determine the coordinates of a certain string within the PDF. Is there a function that allows us to do that? I see a similar `getAnnotations()` method in PDF.js, but none that would allow us to do a text search.

Comment: that gives the entire text, but not the coordinates of specific text items within the doc, or did I miss something?

Comment: It gives you entire transform matrix (with offset, scaling and rotation) of every text run. See TextContent and TextItem definitions https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L721

Comment: @Animesh I'm trying to do the same thing, did you ever end up solving this?